# Does GoogleMock make me implement destructor in mock class?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I keep getting these errors when running make:

```
debug/main.o: In function `MockMQAdapter<SomeClass>::MockMQAdapter()':
/source/Tests/testsfoo/MockMQAdapter.h:30: undefined reference to `MQAdapter<SomeClass>::~MQAdapter()'
debug/main.o:(.rodata._ZTVN2TW9MQAdapterI6ThingyEE[_ZTVN2TW9MQAdapterI6ThingyEE]+0x10): undefined reference to MQAdapter<SomeClass>::~MQAdapter()'
debug/main.o:(.rodata._ZTVN2TW9MQAdapterI6ThingyEE[_ZTVN2TW9MQAdapterI6ThingyEE]+0x18): undefined reference to `MQAdapter<SomeClass>::~MQAdapter()'
debug/main.o:(.rodata._ZTVN2TW9MQAdapterI6ThingyEE[_ZTVN2TW9MQAdapterI6ThingyEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `MQAdapter<SomeClass>::publish(std::string const&, std::string &message)'
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

template<typename S>
class MQAdapter {
public:
    MQAdapter(const std::string host, uint16_t port);
    virtual ~MQAdapter();
    virtual void publish(const std::string queue, std::string message);
};

MQAdapter::MQAdapter(const std::string host, uint16_t port) {}

//Generated by gmock_gen.py
template <typename T0>
class MockMQAdapter : public MQAdapter<T0> {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD2_T(publish,
      void(std::string, std::string));
};
```

I followed the google mock guides pretty closely. I don't understand what these errors mean. Here's what my test looks like:

```
TEST(MyTest, ExpectCall) {
  MockMQAdapter<SomeClass> *adapter = new MockMQAdapter<SomeClass>("host", 1);
  EXPECT_CALL(*adapter, publish("hi", "hello"));
  adapter->publish("hi", "hello");
}
```

Comment: Are the first and second code snippets in different translation units (C++ files)?

Comment: Why haven't you defined `~MQAdapter()`?

Comment: http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#making-the-compilation-faster

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `MQAdapter` destructor, but not defined it. Thus the linker complains when it tries to resolve it. Provide a definition, `default` would be enough, i.e. `virtual ~MQAdapter() = default;`.

On the other hand, the definition of the constructor should be inline or qualified with the template parameter:

```
template <typename S>
MQAdapter<S>::MQAdapter(const std::string host, uint16_t port) {}
```

I guess it's because that's just an example, but you are not using the `MQAdapter` template parameter for anything, so it could be a regular class.